# SOAP Libraries Implementing WS-ReliableMessaging

Tags: soap, ws-reliablemessaging

I'm looking for SOAP libraries that implement WS-ReliableMessaging. So far I've come across Apache's Sandesha implementation for Axis. Are there any other frameworks that provide an implementation of the WS-ReliableMessaging specification?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this for .net or java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's WCF implements WS-ReliableMessaging using the wsHttpBinding protocol.

See:

- [Introduction to Reliable Messaging in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx)
- [WS-ReliableMessaging interoperability between WCF and Sun WSIT](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2007/07/09/ws-reliablemessaging-interoprability-between-microsoft-wcf-and-sun-wsit.aspx)

Marc

Answer (score 0):

The Sun JAX-WS Reference Implementation (aka "Metro") claims to implement WS-RM, although I haven't tried it, and don't know how capable it is. It comes as part of Glassfish, or you can use use it standalone.

https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/index.html